# javascript - function inside an object literal

Tags: javascript

Just examples, the example #1 works, but is it possible to pass the "argument" to a function inside an object value as in example #2?
 Example #2 does not work, what do I need?

Example 1

```
var CANINE = { 
    DOG: function(){
        CANINE.DOG_RACE(prompt("Dog name:"));
    },

    DOG_RACE: function(name) {
        alert("Retriever's name:" + name);
    }
}
```

Example 2

```
    var CANINE = { 
         DOG: function(){
             CANINE.DOG_RACE.retriever(prompt("Dog name:"));
         },
         DOG_RACE: function(){
             function retriever(name){
                alert("Retriever's name:" + name); 
             }
         }
    }
```

Call function

```
onClick="CANINE.DOG()"
```

Comment: Learn to indent!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your second example should be like this:

```
var CANINE = { 
     DOG: function(){
         CANINE.DOG_RACE.retriever(prompt("Dog name:"));
     },
     DOG_RACE: {
          retriever: function(name){
            alert("Retriever's name:" + name); 
         }
     }
}
```